# Passing extra arguments to function checkNotAuthenticated

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to write a function that checks whether the user is authenticated or not, and if they are, redirect them to a specific page, which is passed through the same function. This is how I thought I could do it:

```
function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next, redirect) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect(redirect)
}

app.post("/login", checkNotAuthenticated("/account"), passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: "/account",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
}))
```

However, this method does not pass the `req`, `res` and `next` arguments. Those are only passed when I call the function without the parentheses (`checkNotAuthenticated`), being filled in for me. How can I run my own argument for the redirect through the same function? Or, is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of the parameters and use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
function checkNotAuthenticated(redirect, req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect(redirect)
}

app.post("/login", checkNotAuthenticated.bind(null, "/account"), passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: "/account",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
}))
```